# How can i align two images with CSS, the one in Upper Rigth position and the other in Down-right position?

Tags: html, css

How can i align two images with CSS, the one in Upper Rigth position and the other in Down-right position?

Here is the markup

```
<th class="X" scope="col">
Time
<input id="ORAAsc" class="up" type="image" style="border-width:0px;" src="" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl02$ORAAsc">
<input id="Desc" class="down" type="image" style="border-width:0px;" src="" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl02$ORADesc">
</th>
```

and the CSS

```
.X {
    height:33px;
    background-color:#DEDEDD;
    width:75px;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-right:80px;
    margin-left:80px;
}





.up{What should i place here?}

.down{What should i place here?}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Are you trying to align two images in the .X, both to the right, one on top of the other?

Comment: @Alpaus I would like to align the images within  the X but with absolute positions. The one should stick to the upper right corner and the other to the right lower corner

Answer (score 1):

jacktheripper is right. It's usually a good idea to add one other thing to the containing element when using absolute positioning:

```
   .x{
    position:relative;
}
```

This will ensure that the images will be absolutely positioned relative to that of their container.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.up {
top: 0;
right: 0;
position: absolute;
}

.down {
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: "down: 0px" -> "bottom: 0" (no need to add "px" to 0 either)